# Saving data to Room from androidx.work.Worker fails

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-workmanager

I´ve tried saving data from a Worker to Room database.

**Versions:**

- Work Runtime Ktx - android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.0-alpha02
- Room - android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0 and
  android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private fun runDataDownloadWork() {
        WorkManager.getInstance()
                .beginWith(dwElementTypesWork)
                .then(dwElementsWork)
                .enqueue()
        WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusById(dwElementsWork!!.id)
                .observe(this, Observer { workStatus ->
                    if (workStatus != null && workStatus.state.isFinished) {
                        Log.d("WorkManager", "dwElementsWork finished")
                    }
                })
    }

    private fun createWorkRequests() {
        dwElementsWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DWElementsWork>()
                .addTag(DWElementsWork.TAG)
                .setConstraints(wifiConstraints)
                .build()
        dwElementTypesWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DWElementTypesWork>()
                .addTag(DWElementTypesWork.TAG)
                .setConstraints(wifiConstraints)
                .build()
    }
```

**DWElementsWork.kt**

```
class DWElementsWork : Worker() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "dw_elements_work"
    }

    override fun doWork(): WorkerResult {

        val apiService: APIService = ServiceGenerator
            .createService(applicationContext, MyAPIService::class.java)
        var elementDao: ElementDao? = AppDatabase 
            .getInstance(context = applicationContext)
            .elementDao()

        val response = apiService.getElements().execute()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val elements = response.body()
            try {
                elementDao?.insertElements(elements!!)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                return WorkerResult.SUCCESS
            }
        }
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_WORKER", response.errorBody()?.string())
        return WorkerResult.FAILURE
    }
}
```

**AppDatabase.kt**

```
@Database(entities = [
    (Element::class)
], version = 9, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun elementDao(): ElementDao

    companion object {

        private var sInstance: AppDatabase? = null

        /**
         * Gets the singleton instance of AppDatabase.
         *
         * @param context The context.
         * @return The singleton instance of AppDatabase.
         */
        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = Room
                        .databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            AppDatabase::class.java,
                            "my_database.db"
                        )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
            }
            return sInstance!!
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem resides when trying to call `elementDao?.insertElements(elements!!)` it gives the follwing error:

**StackTrace**

```
06-20 15:57:09.660 25193-25226/com.myapp.app E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '/data/user/0/com.myapp.app/databases/my_database.db' is not open.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked(SQLiteDatabase.java:2287)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:409)
        at android.database.sqlite.-$$Lambda$RBWjWVyGrOTsQrLCYzJ_G8Uk25Q.get(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:284)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:403)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession(SQLiteProgram.java:101)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:45)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(InvalidationTracker.java:321)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I´ve stopped the debugger right before inserting the elements and `AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).isOpen` returns **false**.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is it possible to save data from Workers to Room?

Maybe **applicationContext** (getApplicationContext()) is not giving the appropriate context and AppDatabase it´s badly instantiated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version of Room and WorkManager? They are currently to 1.1.1 and 1.1.0-alpha3 respectively. (just to be sure it's not a know bug fixed in the latest version)

Comment: Have you tried to do this from empty state? Such exception can be thrown if migration failed.

Comment: The app started working flawlessly at some point, @MatPag updated both libraries after that either way. Didn't do anything different, maybe a clean install as iDemigod stated.

Comment: @iDemigod starting it from emtpy state seems to fix that, but I´ve fallbackToDestructiveMigration option active and since I don't have any Migration scheme created it should delete the database and recreate it from zero. Don't know why at some point it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using  `abstract fun elementDao(): ElementDao` as a function instead of  `abstract val elementDao: ElementDao`?  That looks suspicious to me. Also is a good practice initializing your database in your App class as a lateinit var singleton created on the App's onCreate() callback.

Comment: in **runDataDownloadWork()** why you are using different instance from **WorkManager** ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's obsolete and the official answer by the library engineer has been deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Yes @keyboardsurfer you are right, will delete the question now as is too old, also I think I cannot replicate it again.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer why was the official answer deleted and where can I see deleted answers?